# How to get the value of input hidden html from text editor to custom page template?

Tags: php, customization, page-template, forms, html

I have 10 or more input hidden in 10 or more pages with different values in Wordpress text editor and I want to get the value using $_POST in a custom page template.

How to do this? I tried to called the input hidden name in my custom page template but the value is not getting.

Text editor

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="segment" value="test"/>
</form>
```

Custom page template

```
$segment = isset($_POST['segment']) ? $_POST['segment'] : '';
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not specifying a page, then you would access the `$_POST` data on the same page as your form.

```
print_r( $_POST );

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'firstname' ] ) )
{
    echo $_POST[ 'firstname' ] . ' ' . $_POST[ 'lastname' ];

    wp_die();

}
else 
{ 
    ?>

    <form method="POST">

        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>

        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    <?php 

    wp_die();
}
```

If you want to access `$_POST` data on another page, you would probably need to specify that in the `action` attribute.

```
<form method="POST" action="your_page_name_here.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="segment" value="test">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: `$_POST` is wrote in the custom page template while the html input hidden tag wrote in the text editor. Do you mean I should call the custom page template php in the text editor?